# Why can't I refer to an interface inside of generic brackets in a variable declaration?

Tags: java

I tried to write the following:

```
public class AdjacencyList<Vertex> {

    Map<Vertex, Set<Edge<Vertex>>> adj = new HashMap<Vertex, HashSet<Edge<Vertex>>>();
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<Vertex,HashSet<Edge<Vertex>>> to Map<Vertex,Set<Edge<Vertex>>>
```

Eclipse wants me to change the line to:

```
Map<Vertex, HashSet<Edge<Vertex>>> adj = new HashMap<Vertex, HashSet<Edge<Vertex>>>();
```

(Note it's specifying the type of `Set` on the left.

I'm trying to get into the habit of specifying interfaces instead of exact types. Why is it not letting me in this case?

Comment: IIRC the terms you should google are `covariance` and `contravariance`. In short words, `List<String>` is not an instance/subclass of `List<Object>` because if it were then issues arise from using the generic type instance as parameters or return types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that unless specifically specified, generics in Java are *invariant*, meaning that (to simplify), a `List<string>` does not inherit from `List<Object>`, even though `String` does inherit `Object`. Consider that a `List<Object>` has an `add(Object o)` method, which, if it was inherited by `List<String>`, be used to add non-Strings to the list and break the very type safety that generics are here to provide us. Similarly, a `Map<Vertex,Set<...>>` isn't the base class of a `Map<Vertex, HashSet<...>>`, even though `Set` is of `HashSet`.

Try reading [this article](https://briangordon.github.io/2014/09/covariance-and-contravariance.html) on Covariance and Contravariance in Java, which explains this issue in general terms, and shows how to use Generic Bounds to extend the possible generic arguments of a type:

> Unbounded wildcards allow assignment with any type parameter:
>
> ```
> List<?> list = new ArrayList<Clazz>();
> ```
>
> Bounded wildcards affect assignment like you might expect:
>
> ```
> List<? extends Clazz> list = new ArrayList<SubClazz>();
> List<? super Clazz> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
> ```

Comment: So should I change the declaration to use bounded wildcard like your last example, or leave it as Eclipse suggested?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. If this was a simple case, I'd say go with whatever looks nicer to you. Since this is a complex declaration and I don't even know how easy it would be to define bounded wildcards for multiple levels of generic nesting, I'd just stay with Eclipse's suggestion.

Comment: Might be clearer to comment that a `HashSet` is a type (or implementation) of `Set`...

Answer (score 1):

Make what you're instantiating concrete (`HashMap`), but keep the generic type abstract. Something like:

```
Map<Vertex, Set<Edge<Vertex>>> adj = new HashMap<Vertex, Set<Edge<Vertex>>>();

adj.put(new Vertex(), new HashSet<Edge<Vertex>>());
```

Note that this will allow other types of `Set` to be used as values in the `Map`, which may or may not be what you intend. If you only want `HashSet`s in the `Map`, then Eclipse's suggestion would be the way to go.